# Library or API for performing checkstyle on source code

Tags: java, checkstyle, linter

I'm experimenting on how I can run check style on a source code without saving it as a file and run check style through ANT. Are there any libraries or APIs available in check style to trigger checks from Java code? How any linting libraries(Java API) available for programming languages available for languages other than Java?

Comment: AFAIK, Checkstyle always works on files.